# On Careers, add a filter for jobs that require qualifications

Tags: feature-request, jobs

It's really annoying when you read through a job description, thinking "this looks great", only to find out that they don't hire people who've not been to university, or who haven't been certified as competent by Cisco. There's also a tendency to mention this non-negotiable requirement at the very bottom of the job description.

It disheartens the user, giving them a sense that they're just trawling through crap, undermining their optimism and encouraging them to look at something else.

At least for common requirements, like a relevant university degree, there should be a check similar to the one for remote work, where the employer is required to be specific about prerequisites.